# Latitude of landmarks

Tags: latitude-longitude, geodetic

I am new to mapping. Is there an online resource that lists both the geocentric and geodetic latitudes of various world landmarks?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a particular data set - you may find some help asking over at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OpenStreetMap has POI (Point of Interest) data, to get them see: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15/getting-point-of-interest-data-from-openstreetmap. The WGS84 latitude, longitude can be changed simply to geocentric XYZ coordinates, the formulas can be found in the 2nd chapter of this PDF: http://clynchg3c.com/Technote/geodesy/coordcvt.pdf

Comment: Oh, I did not realize there were several different geodetic latitudes, depending on which organization made the measurements and did the calculations.

Comment: You only need the geodetic latitude.  If you have this, you can easily calculate the geocentric latitude yourself.  (And soon you'll probably discover that it's the parametric latitude you want to use.  Plotting is simpler with this latitude.)